# What languages allow cross-platform native executables to be created?

Tags: programming-languages, executable

I'm frustrated to discover that Java lacks an acceptable solution for creating programs that will run via double-click.  Other than .NET for Windows, what modern and high-level programming languages can I write code in that can be compiled for various platforms and run as a native/binary in each (Windows, Linux, OSX (optional))

Assuming I wanted to write code in python, for instance, is there a cohesive way that I could distribute my software which wouldn't require users to do anything special to get it to run?  I want to write and distribute software for computer-illiterate and Java has turned out to be a real pain in this respect.

**CLARIFICATION**: When i say cross-platform I mean that there are ways I can compile my source code using different compilers for each target system.  I don't need a compile-once solution... I just want a simple experience for users of the software even if I need to compile it and work out code issues for each target platform.

Comment: Java programs may run with double-click on Windows, Linux and Macs.

Comment: **edit** you're doing it wrong. Being cross platform doesn't mean, blind coding.  While wora works for small apps, larger apps do need tuning for each target platform.  Excellent examples are the IDE's which are double-click to install and run for instance "Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA ( or limewire if you want a *street app* reference )   You can go to each one website and you'll find a installable and can be run by computer-illiterates **but** you need to work harder than a simple HelloWorld.jar

Comment: Try Rust. You'll love it! See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Adding [Go](https://golang.org/) to the list.

To enable cross compilation in go you have to [re-compile the runtime and standard library](https://github.com/gophercon/2014-talks/blob/master/kelseyhightower/code/crosscompile.sh#L4-L6):

```
cd /usr/local/go/src
for os in linux windows darwin; do
  GOOS=${os} GOARCH=amd64 ./make.bash —no-clean
done
```

And then specify the target OS before compiling:

```
GOO=linux go build yourprojecthere
```

Comment: Although I recommended Rust as one of the answers here, I fell in love with Go soon afterwards. I'd go for Go over Rust due to its GC making life easier but that's just me. Upvote btw.

Answer (score 8):

C is the closest you're going to get.

The languages that provide for the best cross-platform execution are going to be those that do *not* run native code, like the Java platform and the .NET framework. You can also use an interpreted, rather than compiled, language.

I have been experimenting with Mono and C# with Winforms.  It has proven to be a pretty good combination so far.  In Windows, the executable can be run by double-clicking on the executable directly, or creating a shortcut for it that can be double-clicked.  In Linux, the executable can be run from an icon that executes a small script, and the user experience is essentially the same.

I think you can expect a similar experience with Python.

Comment: A similar experience to mine with Java, or yours with C#?

Comment: Mine with C#.  The Mono folks created a library that is essentially compatible with Winforms, so anyone who has done that kind of programming before is quite at ease in Mono.  But if you are comfortable with Java, there's no reason I can think of why you can't create programs that run directly from an icon on the desktop on either Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 6):

[Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) should be in this list.

1. Install the Rust toolchain from https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/
2. `cargo new "my_first_rust_progam" --bin`
3. `cd my_first_rust_progam`
4. `cargo run`

No really that's it. No pre-installation requisites for runtimes or frameworks for end users. It's really that simple. You just wrote and compiled a tiny "hello world" source to a native binary and executed it too.

There's nice Documentation at https://doc.rust-lang.org/ to get you started. Learn Rust today!

Comment: Soon after I wrote this answer I took the time to learn Go. I'd say its way better in terms of productivity if you are not developing systems applications. I'd just go with Golang over Rust for about 99% of the server side use cases that I've come across in my entire career. Learn both. You can't go wrong :D

Comment: Ease of learning language != Ease to develop bug-free software. (Case in point: Assembly). See https://fasterthanli.me/articles/some-mistakes-rust-doesnt-catch (compares Go and Rust)

Answer (score 5):

If you're used to Delphi then [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) can provide a similar environment, yet allow cross-platform compilation. Unfortunately you can't just take your VCL components and drop them in, since those tend to be Windows-specific/-centric. Some providers of VCL components do also provide LCL versions though.

Answer (score 5):

### C++

Take Google Chrome. It is a new web browser, and an excellent example of native multiplatform application and it's written in C++.

Of course, they have to *"work out code issues for each target platform"*  as you said, but it certainly works!

Comment: with QT, writing a cross platform c++ app can be pretty rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very good experience with Delphi from Borland compiled in windows, it was perfectly running using Wine, Delphi by default compiles all in one exe. Just avoid to use the Win32-voodoo library.

The other option to cross compile it's C\C++, eclipse and gcc, you can compile also architectures different by i386

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and rather easy to 'compile' Java programs to different platforms. You could convert them to executable .jar files, or you could use a program such as JSmooth.

If you need to be able to compile it for different platforms, you could use an interpreted language like Perl and compile it to C code. Since C can be easily compiled on the target platform, the user does not need an interpreter.

Comment: Cython is interesting. The binary is much smaller than a golang binary

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, your best bet for exacty what you are asking is C, it will compile on almost any platform, as its effectivly a "high-level assembler."

That said, to achieve the goal you want, a managed language is going to be your best bet. Something like Silverlight for Windows/OSX (and Moonlight for Mono on Linux) is going to be your best bet, additionally it will provide code-once deploy everywhere solution.

Adobe Flash/Flex/Air would be another option, which will give you compile once deploy anywhere, I know thats not what you asked for, but it is the closes to achieving the goal of a simple user expeirence.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript always . It's a Interpreted language , cross platform and the source code is directly converted into machine code with the use of interpreter . Any non-computer science background user can use it  just by double-click with out any extra configuration .

Comment: *can use it just by double-click* – *If* the computer has a Javascript interpreter set up that'll execute the file. Not much different than a Java runtime requirement.